# Angular serve Module not found error @angular/forms

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-forms, angular10

when i run ng serve the following error occurs. The problem is I do not import the module in all these components, but the FormsModule in my Modules.
I updated my Angular version to 10.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/soildoc-study/soilstudy-detail/common/dropdown-treeview-custom/dropdown-treeview-custom.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/forms/forms' in 'C:\Users\frankel\Bonares\klibrary\src\app\soildoc-study\soilstudy-detail\common\dropdown-treeview-custom'

ERROR in ./src/app/soildoc-study/soilstudy-detail/management/management.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/forms/forms' in 'C:\Users\frankel\Bonares\klibrary\src\app\soildoc-study\soilstudy-detail\management'

ERROR in ./src/app/soildoc-study/soilstudy-detail/methods/methods.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/forms/forms' in 'C:\Users\frankel\Bonares\klibrary\src\app\soildoc-study\soilstudy-detail\methods'

ERROR in ./src/app/soildoc-study/soilstudy-detail/models/models.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/forms/forms' in 'C:\Users\frankel\Bonares\klibrary\src\app\soildoc-study\soilstudy-detail\models'
```

Hope that anyone can help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement may be wrong. Please try the following:

```js
// app.module.ts

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Yes this is my import statement. Thats why i dont understand why it is not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, without a little more code from you, neither can I : )